# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Updating Multiple Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The findOneAndUpdate method doesn't work properly. I'm trying to update all the fields all at once but it's only updating (setting) the last field. It's always only the last field. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what can I do to have the expected effect?

This is my findOneAndUpdate code:

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate({_id:bookId},{$set:{"name": name},$set:{"genre": genre},$set:{"author": author},$set:{"similar": similar}}).exec(function(err, book){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send(err);
       } else {
            res.status(200).send(book);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are using the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/) operator multiple times. The correct syntax for `$set` is :

```
{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```

You need to change your *update* argument like this:

```
Book.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": bookId }, { "$set": { "name": name, "genre": genre, "author": author, "similar": similar}}).exec(function(err, book){
   if(err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.status(500).send(err);
   } else {
            res.status(200).send(book);
   }
});
```

Comment: What if you wanted to $set and $push in the same findByIdAndUpdate field? How would the syntax look then?

Comment: @55Cancri all you need is to add the `$push: { <field>: <value>, ..}` to the "update" argument:  `{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... }, $push: { <field>: <value>, ..} }`

Comment: @styvane can you plz take a look at this Q https://stackoverflow.com/a/70171269/15454800