# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate doesn't update multiple nested fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**The Problem:** I'm trying to update some nested fields in MongoDb using findOneAndUpdate but it only update one field (date) instead all the fields, actually if I remove the "Date" field it updates nothing.

**Scheme**:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    info : {
         geolocation: {
              latitude: String,
              longitude: String,
              date: Date
         }
    }
})
```

**My Statement:**

```
User.findOneAndUpdate (
    {"_id": id},
    {"$set": {
            'info.geolocation.latitude': 'test-lat',
            'info.geolocation.longitude': 'test-long',
            'info.geolocation.date': moment()
        }
    }).exec(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            mongodb.desconectMDB();
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: 'error'
            });
        } else {
            console.log(doc);
            return  res.status(200).send({
                message: 'success'
            });
        }
    }
);
```

(I already did the accepted answer here [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Updating Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267042/mongoose-findoneandupdate-updating-multiple-fields) which is similar to my issue but it doesn't work in my case)

Comment: How do you determine that `latitude` and `longitude` are not getting updateed ? Did you check `console.log` output or queried the database directly ?

Comment: What are you updating with? You have a static strings in your example. Also moment() is redundant you might as well do new Date()

Comment: @mickl I checks directly in the DB (MongoDB 4.0.9) with Mongo Compass (Version 1.17)

Comment: @Dominic yes, I have static strings to be very sure that I'm sending a content (the fields are String type too) and I use moment() since we prefer to use the "moment" module to set the dates across the project

Comment: @Saymon I tried this from node.js and works as expected (the only thing is new: true parameter which you're probably aware of)

Answer (score 0):

Its not updated in your bdd or console.log(doc) is just displaying the wrong information ?

If console.log(doc) returns the wrong informations just add the following options (  {new: true} ) to return the updated document :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate (
{"_id": id},
{"$set": {
        'info.geolocation.latitude': 'test-lat',
        'info.geolocation.longitude': 'test-long',
        'info.geolocation.date': moment()
    }
},
{new: true}).exec(....
```

Comment: It doesn't update in the DB (MongoDB 4.0.9), therefor it doesn't update in the log neither