# I am getting an error while i am pushing an object to the array property in node js using monogoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

`My Problem is i want after i create the categoryName and then i create the product properties, then i can push the product properties to the categoryProduct field`.

I tried that using $push and it gives me an empty array in the db.

`CallBack Function for creating a product`

```
//Here i am getting the values from the body

//create an object 

const productObject = new productSchema({

    productName: req.body.productName,
    productPrice: req.body.productPrice,
    productCategory: req.body.productCategory,
    productQuantity: req.body.productQuantity,
    productSection: req.body.productSection,
    productExDate: req.body.productExDate

})


    //saving 
    productObject
        .save()
        .then(data => {
            res.redirect('/halalMunchies/all-products');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occured while creating a create operation"
            });
        });

    //pushing inside the productCategory in the category model

    categoryDB.findOneAndUpdate({ categoryName: req.body.productCategory }, { $push: { productsCategory: productObject._id } })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

`the output`

```
  {
  _id: new ObjectId("61a62e619c17c622153c4d1a"),
  categoryName: 'meat',
  productsCategory: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

In the `categoryschema` i have `categoryname` and `productsCategory` contains all the products that this category has.
`Category Schema`

```
    var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    //properties // shape of the documentation

    categoryName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true

    },

    productsCategory: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'productSchema',
        required: true
    }]

});

const categoryDB = mongoose.model('categorySchema', categorySchema);
```

In the `productSchema` one of it's properties is `productCategory` which it references to the `categorySchema`

```
    var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    //defining the properties

    productName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'Product name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    },

    productCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
        ref: 'categorySchema',
        required: [true, 'Category name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    },

    productPrice: {
        type: Float,
        required: [true, 'Price name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    },

    productQuantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Quantity name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    },

    productSection: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Section name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    },

    productExDate: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'ExDate name is required'] // we can pass a message like this 
    }


})

const productDB = mongoose.model('productSchema', productSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way, assuming we're using an async function for the sake of simplicity to avoid .then .catch painful process:

```
const {
  productData,
  productCategory,
} = req.body;

const productObject = new productSchema({ ...productData });

await productObject.save();

const categoryObject = await categorySchema.findOne({ categoryName: productCategory });

if (!categoryObject) {
  // Throw some error
}

await categoryObject.productsCategory.push(productObject._id);
await categoryObject.save();

// then make your redirect to /halalMunchies/all-products
```

---

**EDIT**

```
const {
  productName,
  productPrice,
  productQuantity,
  productSection,
  productExDate,
  productCategory,
} = req.body;

const productObject = new productSchema({
  productName,
  productPrice,
  productCategory,
  productQuantity,
  productSection,
  productExDate,
});

await productObject.save();
```

If you mean by productCategory "category id", then you should fetch by _id:

```
const categoryObject = await categorySchema.findOne({ _id: productCategory });

if (!categoryObject) {
  // Throw some error
}

await categoryObject.productsCategory.push(productObject._id);
await categoryObject.save();

// then make your redirect to /halalMunchies/all-products
```

Comment: `categorySchema.findOne({ categoryName: productCategory });`
this line should return only the categoryName that the user inputted it, and u set it equal to categoryObject so this object has only one attribute. in this `await categoryObject.productsCategory.push(productObject._id);
` productsCategory is undefined.

Comment: According to how you defined your categorySchema above, productsCategory can't be undefined, the code I provided all it's doing is that it fetches for a category with a categoryName equals to  productCategory the one provided on body, and if there's such document, it'll update productsCategory property field by pushing the id of the new created productObject. If  productsCategory is undefined as you're saying there's something wrong when creating your category doc in the first place.

Comment: can you plz take a look again, i updated the way that i created an object to get the body values, how can i do it based on this. thnx for your help

Comment: thanks man for the help