# How to update two fields in one condition in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What im trying to do is to update and push in two different fields when a condition is true, and to update only one field when the condition is false.

```
  const updateQuery = historicEnable == true ? ({ $push: { locationHistoric: locationObject } }, {currentLocation: locationObject}) : ({ currentLocation: locationObject })


  const theLocation = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ phone }, updateQuery, {
    new: true,
  });
```

By far when the condition is true, it pushes only in the locationHistoric, and not updating the currentLocation.

How can I make both of the methods work on the same condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Updating Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267042/mongoose-findoneandupdate-updating-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
const updateQuery = historicEnable == true ?
  ({ $push: { "locationHistoric": locationObject, "currentLocation": locationObject }) :
  ({ $push: { "currentLocation": locationObject } })
```

And you're also missing operator in second statement.
Use any operator like $set or $push

Comment: I understand your logic, but the thing is that I don't want to push in the currentLocation filed, I just want to update it

Comment: and what about this :

const updateQuery = historicEnable == true ? ({ $push: { locationHistoric: locationObject}, $set:{currentLocation: locationObject }}) : ({$set:{ currentLocation: locationObject }})