# how to set current date for createdAt field in mongoDB document?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

Need to set current date to createdAt date field after updating the document. Passing current date value from the front-end react.js app to back-end node.js mongoose.

let's say model name is `post` and set `{ timestamps: true }` this value to automatically create createdAt and updatedAt field.

Passing as a data object from the front-end as below but this doesn't update the field.

```
const date = {
  ...
  createdAt: Date.now()
}
```

this is the back-end query to update the post data.

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({$and: [{_id: new Types.ObjectId(id)}, {postedBy: user}] }, {$set: updatedData}, {new: true})
```

Comment: Your query doesn't seem correct: `Post.findOneAndUpdate({$and: [{_id: new Types.ObjectId(id)}, {postedBy: user}] }, {$set: {createdAt : updatedData}}, {new: true})`. I think it should update the date just make sure the string is first parsed to date if any issues.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara `{$set: updatedData}` this is not a one field. It's array of data with the createdAt field. I just show here only one field.

Comment: May be if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267042/mongoose-findoneandupdate-updating-multiple-fields) helps.